# Zimlet. Получение полной информации о письме

Tags: zimbra, zimlet

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые!

Недавно наш почтовый сервер переехал на Zimbr'y и мне поступил приказ написать пару свистоперделок.

**Вопрос 1**:

Имеется список писем типа zmMailListController.
Требуется получить подробную информацию о каждом письме из этого списка.

Пробовал через метод getMsg(), но почему-то всегда возвращается только последнее письмо. С какими параметрами надо вызывать этот метод? Как получить подробную информацию о письме (например, оригинал письма)?

**Вопрос 2**:

Как штатными средствами Zimbra проверить существование домена, с которого отправлено письмо?

P.S.: если возможно, то не давайте буржуйских ссылок (1. я с ним сильно не дружу, 2. Заколебал он меня за последнюю неделю. 3. Если не сложно поделитесь примером кода)